# running python for multipul urls get no output

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am trying to run a scraper for this website the code works when i just use one url but when i add multi it gives me no output. I need it to run thru the different urls and scrape the information.

```
> Blockquote
>`import requests
>import csv
>from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>from html.parser import HTMLParser
>from time import sleep
from random import randint
<import urllib.request

r=requests.get('https://www.qiagen.com/us/products/a-z-list/#&&s=Ascending&pg=55&q=&l=')
c=r.content
s=BeautifulSoup(c,"html.parser")


product_urls = ['https://www.qiagen.com/us/shop/pcr/primer-sets/miscript-precursor-assays/#orderinginformation', 
'https://www.qiagen.com/us/shop/pcr/primer-sets/miscript-primer-assay-plate/#orderinginformation', 
'https://www.qiagen.com/us/shop/pcr/primer-sets/miscript-primer-assays/#orderinginformation', 
'https://www.qiagen.com/us/shop/genes-and-pathways/technology-portals/browse-qpcr/mirna-gene-expression/mirna-isolation/miscript-single-cell-qpcr-kit/#orderinginformation']

for url in product_urls:
    page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    s = BeautifulSoup(page,"html.parser")

getall = s.find_all("div",{"class":"gene_globe_segment_0_OrderingInfoPane"})
getall

for i in getall:
    product_name = (i.find('div',{'class':'title'}).text.strip())
    product_discription = (i.find('div',{'class': 'copy'}).text.strip())
    product_number = (i.find('td',{'class': 'textLeft paddingTopLess'}).text.strip())
    cat_number = (i.find('td',{'class': 'textRight paddingTopLess'}).text.strip())
    product_price = (i.find('td',{'class': 'textRight paddingTopLess priceSingle'}).text.strip())

for i in getall:
    print(i.find('div',{'class':'title'}).text.strip()) #product name
    print(i.find('div',{'class': 'copy'}).text.strip()) #product discription
    print(i.find('td',{'class': 'textLeft paddingTopLess'}).text.strip()) #product number
    print(i.find('td',{'class': 'textRight paddingTopLess'}).text.strip()) #cat number
    print(i.find('td',{'class': 'textRight paddingTopLess priceSingle'}).text.strip()) #product price

    print(' ')`<
```

Comment: Start with a simple example. What does this simple program print? https://pastebin.com/thPXJ4TD

Comment: it is printing out the details on products on a web page so price, product name, product number and description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got several issues with your script. You have defined faulty `class` names in your main container. Your script is wrongly indented. And finally you need to tune up your selectors in such a way so that it can deal with varying sites. I have curtailed your printing items to two so that I can give you a transparent demonstration. I've tried to clear your mess a little. The modified script I'm pasting below is a working one.

Here you go:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

product_urls = [
'https://www.qiagen.com/us/shop/pcr/primer-sets/miscript-precursor-assays/#orderinginformation', 
'https://www.qiagen.com/us/shop/pcr/primer-sets/miscript-primer-assay-plate/#orderinginformation', 
'https://www.qiagen.com/us/shop/pcr/primer-sets/miscript-primer-assays/#orderinginformation', 
]

for URL in product_urls:
    page = requests.get(URL)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text,"lxml")

    for item in soup.select(".content"):
        product_name = item.select_one('.title').text.strip()
        product_discription = item.select_one('.copy').text.strip()
        print("Name: {}\n\nDescription: {}\n\n".format(product_name,product_discription))
```

Comment: Thank you so much I am new to python. Also I am trying to get the information form the tbody would I just change .content to tbody or the div that contains the rest of the information I am looking for?